# Como trabalhar com testes e fixtures em um banco que contém constraints de chave estrangeira no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, chave-estrangeira, minitest

Estou usando RubyOnRails 4.1 e banco PostgreSQL e utilizo a *gem* [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) para criar restrições de chave estrangeira no banco. Acontece que isso dificulta algumas tarefas com [fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).

Quando tento rodar um teste:

```
spring rake test
```

Costumo ter erros como esse:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "TABELA1" violates foreign key constraint "TABELA2_TABELA1_id_fk" on table "TABELA2"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(980190962) is still referenced from table "TABELA2".
: DELETE FROM "TABELA1"
```

Só consigo rodar meus testes porque recrio o banco antes de rodá-los:

```
RAILS_ENV=test spring rake db:reset && spring rake test
```

Também não consigo usar `rake db:fixture:load` para upar os fixtures para o banco de desenvolvimento, dá o mesmo erro.

Alterar a ordem dos fixtures no arquivo `test_helper.rb` não foi suficiente.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso? Pesquisei bastante na *web* e não descobri uma solução.

Comment: Não tenho conhecimentos em rails, mas por acaso isso pode te ajudar (Foreign key support)? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html

Comment: @gmsantos Interessante... A versão `4.2` (ainda em Beta) vai suportar *foreign keys* nativamente (hoje uso uma *gem*). Porém o link não fala nada sobre *fixtures* e testes, talvez não tenhamos mais esse problema no futuro. Vou pesquisar mais sobre... Obrigado! =) (Por ora, ainda gostaria de uma solução para a versão `4.1`)

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução alternativa é: ao invés de fixtures, trabalhar com [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails). E para limpeza do banco entre os testes, o [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner).

Comment: Se não é uma resposta, é melhor publicar como comentário. Fiz uma edição pra remover o meta-texto, mas sugiro um confere no guia [answer].

Comment: Eu fiquei em dúvida se postava como comentário ou resposta. Como é uma solução alternativa pensei que poderia ser útil como possível resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o erro:

> ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "TABELA1" violates foreign key constraint "TABELA2_TABELA1_id_fk" on table "TABELA2"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(980190962) is still referenced from table "TABELA2".

Você não pode apagar um registro da tabela 1 sem antes remover a referência da tabela 2. Logo, neste caso, apague todas as referências antes de apagar o registro.

Além disso, veja a documentação do [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-constraints.html).

Você poderia criar a referência com `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Logo, ao deletar o registro da tabela 1 as referências da tabela 2 seriam deletadas automaticamente. Existem outras opções que podem ser interessante no seu caso como:

- `RESTRICT`
- `NO ACTION`
- `CASCADE`
- `SET NULL`
- `SET DEFAULT`

Answer (score 1):

Sou o autor original da pergunta, e finalmente consegui resolver este problema de maneira definitiva.

A verdade é que o Rails tenta desativar as *triggers* que verificam as referencias de chave estrangeira antes do *setup* da execução dos testes, quando a base é limpa e os *fixtures* são reinseridos na base. Depois do *setup*, mas antes da execução dos testes, as *triggers* de verificação são reabilitadas.

Acontece que, por questões de segurança, o Postgres só permite que usuários superuser desativem essas *triggers*. (Não confundam o superuser do Linux com superuser do Postgres. São duas coisas diferentes!). Se você estiver logado como um usuário "comum", as *triggers* permanecerão habilitadas e o *setup* falhará.

---

### Solução

Assim, a solução é relativamente simples. Basta tornar seu usuário um superuser no Postgres:

```
ALTER ROLE meuusuario SUPERUSER;
```

E automagicamente tudo funcionará como deveria.